# Difference in behavior when using auto vs explicitly specifying type for a private struct

Tags: c++, c++11, type-deduction

Consider the following code snippet

```
class BST
{
    struct Node
    {
        int data_;
        Node * left_, * right;
    } * root_ = nullptr;

    public:

    Node * getRoot()
    {
        return root_;
    }
};

int main() {
    BST bst;
    auto root1 = bst.getRoot();          // Compiles fine
    BST::Node * root2 = bst.getRoot();   // Gives error
}
```

When fetching the value and assigning to a variable whose type is deduced using auto, the code compiles fine. When explicitly specifying the type, it fails. Why this difference in behavior? I expected both to fail.

Comment: what is the error message exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `struct BST::Node` is private within `class BST`. Remember that `class` defaults to private access for *all* members, not just instance members and functions.

Using `auto` is fine because you never explicitly mention the private type.

Comment: I suppose OP wants to know why the 1st code is fine.